# Replacing s with jw in transfer function when the input function is oscillatory and has exponential decay

Tags: transfer-function, frequency-response, convolution

I understand a version of this question has been asked numerous times before but I could not find an answer to this specific one.

This is how I understood replacing s with jw. From the impulse response,

\$y(t)=\int_0^\infty h(\tau) u(t-\tau)d\tau\$ where \$y,u\$ are output, input.

Taking \$u\$ as \$e^{st}\$, \$y(t)=u(t)*H(s)\$ most of the sources I've found say that it is easier to analyze the system for constant amplitude signals so we replace \$s\$ with \$j\omega\$. I understand  it up to this part.

If \$H(s)\$ = \$\frac{1}{s^2+2s+2}\$ which has a stable pole at \$-1+i\$ and \$u(t)=e^{(-1+i)t}\$ wouldn't that mean the output should be unstable since the denominator of \$H(s)=0\$? I've plotted the results on Simulink and Mathematica and the outputs are stable.

[image: t vs y]

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT(28-oct-19)- Figured it out, I MADE A STUPID MISTAKE \$y(t) \ne  \int_0^\infty h(\tau) u(t-\tau)d\tau\$ but \$y(t) =  \int_0^t h(\tau) u(t-\tau)d\tau\$

Comment: Replacing \$s\$ with \$j \omega\$ only models the case where the input is a continuous sinusoid.  For any other input, you need to stay in the Laplace (\$s\$) domain.

Comment: The roots of the TF denominator (i.e.the poles), by definition, make the TF infinite, but that, in itself, doesn't mean that the TF is unstable. It's the **location** of the poles in the s-plane that determine stability. The transformation \$ s\rightarrow j\omega\$ gives the steady state response to a sinusoidal input, so that's a frequency domain representation, not time domain.

Comment: @Chu if \$H(s)=\frac{1}{s^2+1}\$ and input is \$cos(t)\$ replacing s with \$j\omega\$ makes \$H(j*1)\$ infinity. So when theres no damping the output at steady state with a sinosoidal waveform of resonance frequency takes the output of the system to infinity. Why doesn't the same hold when roots are not on the  \$j\omega\$ line.

Comment: With your H(s) the poles are on the imaginary axis, therefore critically stable and the system will oscillate at 1 rad/sec with no input. It is not unstable, and nothing you apply can make it unstable. Stability has nothing to do with the input signal.If the system is linear and stable, applying a sinusoid will give a steady state output sinusoid at the same frequency. That sinusoid is not of infinite amplitude.

Comment: What would be the magnitude of output with respect to input magnitude when I apply an input sinusoid of resonance frequency be in this case? given \$H(j\omega)=\frac{1}{0}\$

Comment: Your TF is critically stable. Applying a sinusoid at the critically stable frequency is a special case, and will give an infinite amplitude output. If the poles are in the left half plane the system will be stable and the poles will have a negative real part that gives a decaying exponential amplitude to a sinusoidal input.

Comment: ... btw, your proposed input signal, \$e^{(-1+j)t}\$ is not realisable. A function of time cannot be complex.

Answer (score 1):

\$y(t)=\int_0^\infty h(\tau) u(t-\tau)d\tau  <=> Y(s) = H(s)U(s)\$,

\$H(s)\$ = \$\frac{1}{s^2+2s+2} = \frac{1}{(s+1+i)(s+1-i)}\$

Modifing the input \$u(t)\$ so that it is actually a real function (as suggested by Chu).

$$ u(t) = \frac{e^{(-1+i)t} + e^{(-1-i)t}}{2}, $$

$$U(s)= \frac{1/2}{s+1-i} + \frac{1/2}{s+1+i}$$

$$Y(s) = \frac{1}{(s+1+i)(s+1-i)}  \left( \frac{1}{s+1+i}+\frac{1}{s+1-i} \right), $$

$$ =  \frac{1/2}{(s+1+i)(s+1-i)^2} + \frac{1/2}{(s+1+i)^2(s+1-i)}, $$

$$ =  \frac{ \tfrac{1}{2} (s+1+i) }{(s+1+i)^2(s+1-i)^2} + \frac{ \tfrac{1}{2}(s+1-i)}{(s+1+i)^2(s+1-i)^2}, $$

$$ =  \frac{\tfrac{1}{2}/2 (s+1+i+s+1-i) }{(s+1+i)^2(s+1-i)^2}, $$

$$ =  \frac{\tfrac{1}{2} (2s+2) }{(s+1+i)^2(s+1-i)^2}, $$

$$ =  \frac{(s+1) }{(s+1+i)^2(s+1-i)^2}, $$

The denominator of H(s) is \$ (s+1+i)^2(s+1-i)^2 \$, it is not zero.

Comment: by the way, I plotted my result in Octave and got the same curve as the one you got.

Comment: U(s), as stated, does not represent a realisable function of time.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you send in an input which is at a (complex) frequency where H(s) is infinite (e.g. has a pole), this does not make H(s) 'unstable'.

H(s) is the ratio of output:input. Sending in that signal *will* have an output so that Vout(t)/Vin(t) tends to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

In general, \$s\$ is a complex variable. Let's say

$$s=a + j\omega$$

When you substitute \$ j\omega\$ for \$s\$, then you are implicitly assuming that \$a=0\$, and either \$s\$ is purely imaginary, (or less likely, that \$\omega\$, the angular frequency, is allowed to take on complex values).

By assuming that \$s\$ takes on only purely imaginary values, one is implicitly assuming that the transfer function is being applied only to sinusoidal components. Exponential decay (or growth) is ruled out.